# parsing html attributes of tag javascript

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I ran into the following situation and am not able to figure out the solution, i am new to javascript, and I tried to search the internet, but couldn't find a viable solution.
1) I want to get attributes of the tag queried for. For example if I have a tag as follows

```
<a href = "pqr/dl/"> docName </a>
```

how do I get the value of href? By doing

```
el.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

I can get only the value of the tag, i.e., "docName" by doing this.

2) How do I query for the "img" tag?
I have an image tag as follows

```
<img src = "/icons/alpha.gif" alt="[DIR]">
```

if I do

```
console.log(el.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue)
```

it is printing "null" on the console. I need the values of src and alt.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can either use `getAttribute` method, or refer to the property directly with its name. Notice, that (exceptionally) `a.toString()` also returns the value of `href` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the method Element.getAttribute(). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

```
var href = el.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].childNodes[0].getAttribute("href");
var src = el.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].childNodes[0].getAttribute("src");
var alt = el.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].childNodes[0].getAttribute("alt");
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`getAttribute()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp) method.

```js
var href = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("href");
var scr = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("src");
var alt = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("alt");

alert('href:' +href+'         scr:'+scr+'            alt:'+alt);
```

```html
<a href = "pqr/dl/"> docName </a>

<img src = "/icons/alpha.gif" alt="[DIR]">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a")[0].getAttribute('href');
```

and for image:

```
document.querySelectorAll("img")[0];
```